# Сравнение двух объектов в классе Python

Tags: python

Есть код в котором разбивается версия на major, minor, build, revision

```
class VersionComparatorException(Exception):
    pass


class VersionParseException(Exception):
    pass


class Version(object):

    def __init__(self, version, major=0):
        self.major = major
        self.version = version
        ver = version.split('.')
        new_list = [re.sub('\D+', '', i) for i in ver]

        while len(new_list) < 4:
            new_list.append('0')
        print(new_list)
        major = new_list[0]
        minor = new_list[1]
        build = new_list[2]
        revision = new_list[3]
        for i in new_list:
            if len(i)==0:
                raise VersionParseException()


    def __lt__(self, test):
        return self.version < test.version

    def __eq__(self, test):
        return self.version == test.version

    def __ne__(self, test):
        return self.version != test.version
```

print(Version('6.4.2') < Version ('5.5hh.5'))

Cравнивать Version можно только с Version
Как реализовать, что бы при сравнении следующего вида выбрасывало  VersionComparatorException

```
Version("1.0") == 1
Version("2.0") == "2.0"
Version("3.1.2") < [3, 1, 2]
Version("1.5.5") > dict()
```

Comment: есть ли причины не [использовать `distutils.version` или `packaging.version` (через `pkg_resources.parse_version`) как это делает `pip` к примеру](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11887762/4279)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В переопределенных методах сравнения нужно проверять тип переменной **test**. Если **test** не является **Version**, выбрасывайте исключение.

Код, который нужно добавить перед **return** (лучше вынести в отдельную функцию проверки):

```
if not isinstance(test, type(self)):
    raise VersionComparatorException()
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает